# PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, error-handling

I've created a custom session handler to store sessions to my local db:

```
  session_set_save_handler(
    array($this, "s_open"),
    array($this, "s_close"),
    array($this, "s_read"),
    array($this, "s_write"),
    array($this, "s_destroy"),
    array($this, "s_gc")
  );
```

Every function works fine except when I try to destroy a session using the native `session_destroy()` func via my custom `s_destroy()` func. While it does destroy the session record back in my db, it crashes the browser on the client side.

In my php log I get the following error message:

> PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined Method Database::close() in .../session.php on line 47

Here is the logic for my s_close method that contains the line which the error is appearing:

```
public function s_close(){
       // Close the database connection
       // If successful
       if($this->db->close()){ //error appears on this line
           // Return True
            return true;
        }
    // Return False
    return false;
}
```

What seems to be the issue?

**UPDATE:**

My **$db** var is an instance of my **Database Class** which uses the PDO API. Here is the class markup:

```
class Database {
      private $host = "localhost";
      private $port = "8889";
      private $user = "admin";
      private $pass = "admin10";
      private $dbname = "items";

      private $dbh;
      private $error;
      private $stmt;

      public function __construct(){
          // Set DSN
          $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';port=' . $this->port . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

          // Set options
          $options = array(
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
          );
          // Create a new PDO instanace
          try{
              $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
          }
          // Catch any errors
          catch(PDOException $e){
              $this->error = $e->getMessage();
          }
      }
```

Now I do not have a function entitled **close()** in this class, which probably is the reason for the error being thrown, however when I do add a **close()** func, it doesn't delete the session row back in my db, as it does without a **close()** func.

Here is the logic for my `s_destroy()` func:

```
public function s_destroy($id){
  // Set query
  $this->db->query('DELETE FROM session WHERE id = :id');

  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

  // Attempt execution
  // If successful
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }

  // Return False
  return false;
}
```

Comment: So the browser actually crashes and shuts down or freezes or just shows a blank page or what does it do?

Comment: No, it shows a page enititled "safari cannot open page localhost:8888/logout.php because connection was dropped", however like I said, back in my Db, the session was destroyed accordingly @Rasclatt

Comment: Obviously there is no close() method for whatever `Database` class the object `$this->db` is defined as.
For debugging, I suggest you run `print_r(get_class_methods($this->db))` right before you try the close(). This will tell you what methods exist for that object.

Comment: I'm basically attempting to check if the db connection is closed... is there a method for doing such a task that i can implement in my database class? @BillKarwin

Comment: I have no idea what API you're using in your Database class, but if you're using, mysql, then [mysqli::close()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) is a function. For PDO, there is no close method, you just destroy the PDO object, and that closes the MySQL connection. You can use `unset($pdo)`.

Comment: You could put `$this->db->close()` inside an if statement checking if `$this->database` isn't empty and is set. That should get rid of your php error.

Comment: my Database class uses PDO, and please check updated question @BillKarwin

Comment: please check updated question @william205

Comment: PDO doesn't have a close method. You can close the database connection with `unset $this->db`.

Comment: well this is extremely unusual because when I leave the code as it is, despite the `php fatal error` for an undefined `close()` method, the session row back in my db gets deleted as it should. However, when I attempt to actually add a `close()` method to my `Database Class` to silence the error, While it silences the error, the destroy method isn't working anymore. I'm at a loss @BillKarwin

Comment: Well, that may be a completely different problem. But the error you originally asked about should be clear to you now. Perhaps you should share the code for your `s_destroy()` method in another question.

Comment: but i know there isn't any syntax issue with my `s_destroy()` method because it works when i don't have a `close()` method to my class. However when I do add a `close()` method, the `s_destroy()` func doesn't work anymore. Seems more like an issue with the closing of this PDO connection @BillKarwin

Comment: Well since you won't show the code, it'll remain a mystery. Good luck with your project!

Comment: check updated question, I've added my s_destroy() method logic @BillKarwin

Comment: Okay, I see that you run SQL queries in your `s_destroy()` method. But if you have already closed the db connection in the `s_close()` method, how can that submit the delete SQL statement? I think your `s_close()` method should commit any pending writes, but not close the db connection.

Comment: Right, I was doing research regarding the sequence in which the session handler methods were fired. What logic would suggest I use in my `s_close()` method to make sure it doesn't close the connection prior to any writes being executed? @BillKarwin

Comment: Just *don't* close the database connection. If you have session data that hasn't been written to the database, then write it and commit. But you probably already do that in `s_write()`. So perhaps there's nothing to do in `s_close()`.

Comment: I mean even when I have not a single character of code in `s_close()`, my `s_destroy()` method doesn't work. It's weird. It's like my `s_destroy` Only fires when I have that faulty error causing code in my `s_close()` @BillKarwin